# JSON Deserialization Exception

Tags: c#, json, wpf

I made a code to parse this [JSON](http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/122/teams)

I've generated the class with JSON2C#:

```
public class Link
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string soccerseason { get; set; }
}

public class Self
{
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Fixtures
{
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Players
{
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Links
{
    public Self self { get; set; }
    public Fixtures fixtures { get; set; }
    public Players players { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public Links _links { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string shortName { get; set; }
    public string squadMarketValue { get; set; }
    public string crestUrl { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Link> _links { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public List<Team> teams { get; set; }
}
```

I perform the request on this way:

```
 private void League_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string requestUrl = "http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/122/teams";
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    string responseText;
    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    using (var responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        responseText = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
    }

    List<RootObject> obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(responseText);

    foreach (var item in obj)
    {
        Home.Items.Add(item.name);
    }
}
```

the compiler return me:

> ```
>  Unhandled Exception "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException" in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g {"name":"value"}) into type "System.Collections.Generic.List"1
> [Test.MainWindow+RootObject]" because the type requires a Json array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
> ```

on the obj deserialization.

How can I fix it? How can i choose the correct deserialization?

Comment: Try http://www.httputility.net/json-to-csharp-vb-typescript-class.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to deserialize it into a list of `RootObject` but in reality the JSON is just a single root object.

Try

```
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseText);
```

instead. And then of course you need to change your for loop because `obj` is no longer a `List<>`. If you want to iterate through the teams, then:

```
foreach (var item in obj.teams)
{
    Home.Items.Add(item.name);
}
```

Comment: Okay, but now in the obj of the foreach I get an underlined in red, in particolar the compiler show the message: the instruction foreach can't work with variable of type Test.MainWindow.RootObject because not contain an GetEnumerator definition.

Comment: `obj` is no longer a list, so you wouldn't be able to iterate through it. You want to iterate through something, I'm guessing the teams. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Ok, thank for your help, I really appreciate your anserw thank you!